# JavaScript Alerts in iOS 7 Fullscreen Web Apps Broken?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, objective-c

JavaScript alerts, prompts and confirmations don't seem to be working when invoked from a fullscreen web app run from the homescreen. They work fine when in Safari, just not when run fullscreen from the home screen. I submitted a bug request but maybe I'm missing something special in iOS 7?

Here's sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Fullscreen Web App Alert Test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="javascript: alert('Hello World');">This is an alert</a></p>
<p><a href="javascript: s = prompt('Enter something');">This is a prompt</a></p>
<p><a href="javascript: confirm('Are you sure?');">This is a confirmation</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Something as basic as `alert()` or `prompt()` behaviour would most likely not be altered... It sounds like you've discovered a bug to me!

Comment: Actually, what are you using as your web app wrapper? Do you mean you're just clicking 'Add to home screen' from safari or are you using something like Phone Gap?

Comment: Out of curiosity, _why_ are you _still_ using iOS 7 beta 5?

Comment: Other than beta version, also not getting clear output

Answer (score 0):

It's a [bug](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review) that was fixed in iOS 7.0.3.